# making a variables in loop where every instance is different

Tags: c

I am working on a poject for school where I need to make a hashMap.
I create a new HashEntry for every new Key. However I found out that they are all the same instance in memory, so I get a hashMap full of the same value. Does Someone know how to create a new instance of a variable within a loop? Or do i need take a different aproach?

```
for (int i = 0; i < amountOfRecords; ++i) {
    scanf("%s %d", tempKey, &tempValue);
    if (!putValue(hashMap, length, tempKey, tempValue)) { //putvalue returns 1 when value is found and is also added
        struct HashEntry hashEntry = newHashEntry(NULL, tempValue, tempKey);
        putHashMap(hashMap, length, &hashEntry); // This handles putting a new entry in
    }
}
```

Comment: You will have to provide a [mre] to allow answering your question.

Comment: I would guess you need to copy the `tempKey` rather than simply referencing it.  But you haven't shown the code for `newHashEntry`

Comment: Storing a pointer to a local variable that ceases to exist on the next iteration or exit from the loop is a recipe for sadness.

Comment: `struct HashEntry hashEntry` is a local variable which goes out of scope when the code leaves the `if` block. Storing its address in the hash map is undefined behavior. You probably need dynamic memory allocation. See [`malloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc) (Without seeing the code or documentation of `newHashEntry` deduct from the code that it must return a structure value which has to be assigned to some structure variable or to a dereferencted structure pointer.)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I hoped I could do without malloc, I see now that that was stupid.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. To understand the problem properly, we would probably need to see the definition of `HashEntry` and whatever the type of `hashMap` is, as well as the functions being called here. Please read [mre].

Comment: " I hoped I could do without malloc, I see now that that was stupid." Again, it will depend on how the data structures in question are actually defined. In general, you need to think about who is responsible for the memory, and about whether it will be copied into another structure, merely referenced from there, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the easiest way to sort this problem out is to allocate it dynamically.

```
        struct HashEntry *hashEntry = malloc(sizeof(*hashEntry));
        if(hashEntry)
        {
            *hashEntry = newHashEntry(NULL, tempValue, tempKey);
            putHashMap(hashMap, length, hashEntry); // This handles putting a new entry in
        }
        else
        {
            /* error handling */
        }
```